# UIWebView actual content height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have taken a web view  and load html like this

```
NSMutableString *myDescriptionHTML = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n"
   "<head> \n"
   "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
   "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
   "</style> \n"
   "</head> \n"
   "<body>%@</body> \n"
   "</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:40], messageModel.content];
```

i want to set web view height to web view content size height after web view loaded html content

Tried ways

1)

```
CGRect frame = self.webViewMain.frame;
frame.size.height = 1;
self.webViewMain.frame = frame;
CGSize fittingSize = [self.webViewMain sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
frame.size = fittingSize;
self.webViewMain.frame = frame;
Height = fittingSize.height;
NSLog(@"size: %f, %f", fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
[tableViewMain reloadData];
```

its too long height

2)

```
Height = [[self.webViewMain stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue];
```

3)

```
Heiht = self.webViewMain.scrollView.contentSize.Height
```

But no one is actual height

help me thanks....

Comment: I successfully used your 3rd approach, but there were updates to `scrollView` height after `webView` finished loading, so i ended up observing `webView.scrollView.contentSize` and updating `webView` height on each change.

Answer (score 0):

UIWebview is a subclass of UIScrollview so you can set Webview.content size using CGSize. That will set your web view content height and width as required.

Comment: yes i tried webViewHeight = self.webViewMain.scrollView.contentSize.Height   but not working properly